# Locate records, in a table, that have had no activity in the past weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to locate records (work orders), in a table, that have had no activity in the past weeks.
  I need to select distinct work orders from the table where the date field is not within the past two weeks from the current date.

I can get the work orders where there are dates older than the past two weeks.

```
select distinct WorkOrder 
from SMWorkOrder 
where SMCo = 1 and WorkOrder in 
           (select WorkOrder 
            from SMWorkCompleted 
            where SMCo = 1 and Date <  DATEADD(WEEK, -2, GETDATE()))
```

How do I get work orders that have lines in this table dated older than the past two weeks and also do not have any lines within in the past two weeks?

Comment: This is a bit confusing.  What does your table look like?  Are you saying a work order can and also cannot have activity within the past two weeks?  Also which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Is the smco on SWorkCompleted or SWorkOrder or both?

Comment: SMWorkOrder table holds all the WOs.  SMWorkCompleted holds the activity on the work orders. Each "activity" is a line in the SMWorkCompleted table and includes the date field.  This table also has the WO.  SMCo is in both tables and needs to be restricted to just 1.

I want to to get all the work orders that haven't had activity (a new entry in SMWorkCompleted table) in the past two weeks.  A work order could have lines in that table that have dates within the past two weeks and prior.  That work order I would not want to see. Just the ones that have *only* lines prior to the past two weeks

Comment: what if they have no lines at all in SMWorkCompleted?

Comment: I'm going through and spot checking the results. The first query you listed below is returning work orders with no lines in SMWorkCompleted as well as those that fall into the appropriate date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a left outer join really works well in situations like this:

```
SELECT
    o.WorkOrder
FROM
    SMWorkOrder o
    LEFT JOIN SMWorkCompleted c
    ON o.WorkOrder = c.WorkOrder
    AND c.Date >= DATEADD(WEEK,-2,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND c.Date <= GETDATE()
    AND c.SMCo = 1
WHERE
    c.WorkOrder is NULL
    AND o.SMCo = 1
```

But note I doubt you have SMCo on both tables perhaps you do but you should remove it from the where condition if not on the SWorkOder table and/or remove it from the ON condition of the join if on the SWorkCompleted Table

For the IN method you actually want to use NOT IN:

```
SELECT
    o.WorkOrder
FROM
    SWorkOrder o
WHERE
    o.SMCo = 1
    AND o.WorkOrder NOT IN (
       SELECT
          WorkOrder
       FROM
          SMWorkCompleted c
       WHERE
          c.Date >= DATEADD(WEEK,-2,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND c.Date <= GETDATE()
          AND c.SMCo = 1
    )
```

NOTE DO NOT USE IN if WorkOrder could be NULL!

The NOT EXISTS method works pretty well too:

```
SELECT
    o.WorkOrder
FROM
    SWorkOrder o
WHERE
    o.SMCo = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT
          WorkOrder
       FROM
          SMWorkCompleted c
       WHERE
          c.WorkOrder = o.WorkOrder
          AND c.Date >= DATEADD(WEEK,-2,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND c.Date <= GETDATE()
          AND c.SMCo = 1
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the input!  However, each of these queries is pull ALL work orders from the SMWorkOrder table.

I want to to get all the work orders that haven't had any activity (a new entry in SMWorkCompleted table) in the past two weeks, but may have had activity prior to the past two weeks

Comment: That would only be true if ALL work orders do not have a c.Date in the last 2 weeks.

Comment: or the SMCo = 1 on SMWorkCompleted is causing the issue if that would exclude all of the activities in the last 2 weeks.

Comment: You're right!  I forget to add one more restriction in the where clause to weed out closed WOs.  Once I did that, it appears the data is accurate! Thanks so much for your assistance!

Answer (score -1):

try using MAX date to subset your work orders...

Comment: This is definitely more of a comment than an answer/solution and I am not sure what you are trying to suggest.